# Why can't I have two col-sm-6 side by side?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In my home page https://balmainmassage.com.au I have a responsive image in a col-sm-6 class on the left and another on the right, same class. Firther down, I have two long images (fw.png and supertuesday.png) inside a class col-sm-5 div. It's col-sm-5 because a col-sm-6 get the two img to move to the left under the figh480tjpg image. So the two long images are shorter than they should be. Any advice?

Thanks so much

Claudio

Comment: I do not understand your problem at all.

Comment: You always have to nest bootstrap's grid like `.container`, then a `.row` and then one of the `col-*` classes. I think you don't have those `.row` classes and nest `.col-*` inside `.col-*` classes

Comment: You should not add your own site as an example. In the future, the site will change and no one will understand your problem and the question will not be useful. Take a look at: http://www.bootply.com/

Comment: The `.col-xs-6` class is on the `img` on the left, not in a container around it. Try doing that and/or remove the `margin-right` on the `img`. It messes up Bootstrap's grid. The idea is to use Bootstrap's grid classes to create a grid, and only inside that grid add your own elements and classes. If you add classes / overwrite classes on Bootstrap's grid elements you're really likely to break the grid.

Comment: thanks ckuijjer, I see what you mean. I've fixed it now.

Comment: thanks Zanon, I get your point. Sort of new to this game - apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really difficult to explain the changes necessary to fix what you've got. As others have said, the way Bootstrap is meant to work is you nest columns within rows. You can't nest a column directly inside of another column and expect it to behave properly. You need to declare another row first. However, the way you have it at the time I am looking at the website, that isn't your problem.

Essentially what you want at the highest level is two columns where the left column is the fight picture and the right column is all of the buttons and other stuff. Therefore, you would need to change your elements to look as the following:

[image: new html]

I hate to use a picture here since it's not SEO-friendly, but really the changes are too complex without any base code to edit (I had to do it in Chrome DevTools).

This gets you this result:

[image: final result]

As others have stated, I definitely would not use margins on columns unless you really know what you're doing. You should really let Bootstrap handle the grid.

Comment: Thanks Rob W, I revised the code along the lines you suggested - much cleaner and it works.